How to exclude classed from @ImportAutoConfiguration in spring boot test
Let's have such configuration class:
@Configuration
@ImportAutoConfiguration(classes = {DataSourceConfig.class })
public class AppConfig {}

And some test:
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
public class SecurityIntegrationTest {}

When I run the test, the beans introduced in @ImportAutoConfiguration are being executed, which is not an intended behaviour and the test fail.
I tried to annotate the test with:
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters={@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = DataSourceConfig.class)})

but it had no effect. I tried to provide a test configuration:
@TestConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceConfig.class })
public class LocalTestConfiguration {}

but it fails too:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes: DataSourceConfig

So what's the approach to take in Spring boot 2.7 to avoid Spring to load the classes mentioned in AppConfig?

I would switch between the configuration classes using a profile.

Yes, this is the way I took as well.

I used profiles to achieve this effect:
@Profile("!test")
@Configuration
@ImportAutoConfiguration(classes = {DataSourceConfig.class })
public class AppConfig {}

and
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class SecurityIntegrationTest {}

